# Stop directory listing without .htaccess in a PHP website

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory-listing

My website host does not allow `.htaccess`. Now how do I stop directory listing in this situation?

Is there any option(s) other than `index.php/index.html` & `.htaccess`?

Comment: Have you tried talking to an admin of your host and explaining the situation?

Comment: What's wrong with an index.htm?

Comment: I think the only other option would be to prevent directory listings in the apache config. But that is probably something you dont have access to.So you either need to talk to your host or put an index.htm in every directory.

Comment: @Olaf I have like 10 folders, so I'll have to add index.html to every single of them :(

Comment: @Black, adding an index.htm to something like ten folders is a clean solution and takes less than a minute...

Answer (score 3):

As you know, on an Apache server a directory listing is only given if there is no index.htm, index.html, index.php etc in the directory you are going to.

So the easiest solution, is a blank index.php in every folder - especially seeing as you are unable to change the config yourself.

I wrote the following code a little while ago - you put it in every folder you don't want people to get a directory listing of - it returns the user to the index of the site they attempted to visit.

**You need to have a README.txt file in the root of the directory for this to work - or just change it to a file that is there.**

```
<?php
    $i=0;
    while(!file_exists('README.txt')){
        chdir("..");
        $i--;
    }
    header("Location: ".substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],0,strrpos(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),'/',$i)));
?>
```

An easier alternative to the above is just:

```
<?php header("Location: /"); ?>
```